# Kubernetes pod can't access other pods exposed by a service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

New to Kubernetes.

To build our testing environment, I'm trying to set up a PostgreSQL instance in Kubernetes, that's accessible to other pods in the testing cluster.

The pod and service are both syntactically valid and running. Both show in the output from `kubectl get [svc/pods]`. But when another pod tries to access the database, it times out.

Here's the specification of the pod:

```
# this defines the postgres server
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  hostname: postgres
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
  containers:
    - name: postgres
      image: postgres:9.6.6
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ports:
      - containerPort: 5432
        protocol: TCP
```

And here is the definition of the service:

```
# this defines a "service" that makes the postgres server publicly visible
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    protocol: TCP
```

I'm certain that something is wrong with at least one of those, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with Kubernetes to know which.

If it's relevant, we're running on Google Kubernetes Engine.

Help appreciated!

Comment: how do you hit postgres db from other pod?

Comment: Are pods and Postgres on the same namespace? How are you trying to connect to Postgres from your app? Which DNS/hostname are you using?

Comment: @fiunchinho Yes, both the pods are in the same dev namespace. For our app, we've got something in Python that uses SQLAlchemy. We're also using the `tenacity` package to handle retrying, so we're eventually just getting a time-out related error from `tenacity`.

Comment: can you share the connection string?

Comment: Glad to: `f'postgresql+psycopg2://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_address}:{db_port}/{db_name}'`. All the `db_x` variables are just from secrets.

Comment: can you try to exec into one of your containers (preferably the python container) and try to curl postgres:5432? also - is the service supposed to be exposed outside the cluster? you can try for testing purposes to remove type: ClusterIP